# TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was looking at some `python 2.x` code and attempted to translate it to `py 3.x` but I'm stuck on this section. Could anyone clarify what is wrong?

```
import random

emails = {
    "x": "[REDACTED]@hotmail.com",
    "x2": "[REDACTED]@hotmail.com",
    "x3": "[REDACTED]@hotmail.com"
}

people = emails.keys()

#generate a number for everyone
allocations = range(len(people))
random.shuffle(allocations)
```

This was the error given:

```
TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

In Python 3, `range` returns a lazy sequence object - it does not return a list. There is no way to rearrange elements in a range object, so it cannot be shuffled.

Convert it to a list before shuffling.

```
allocations = list(range(len(people)))
```

Comment: Do you happen to know the equivalent of xrange for python3?

Comment: Python3's `range` is identical to python2's `xrange`. The old `range` no longer exists.

Comment: it returns a range object which is a sequence type

Answer (score 0):

if you can use numpy library you can replace `range` with `np.arange`:

```
import numpy as np
allocations = np.arange(len(people))
```

Comment: It's way overkill to import `numpy` for this, when it can be done natively just by using `list()`.