# Choose list of lists element unique to row and column (N Queens)

Tags: python, n-queens

I have a list of lists of `-` characters which acts as a grid.

I want to change one `-` to a `Q` per col and row.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
   import pprint 
   import random # I import these classes
   grid = [['-'] for n in range(8)]
   for i in range (8):
       for j in range(8):
           inserPoint = random.randrange(8,8)
           if (j == inserPoint or i == inserPoint) and (grid[j] != 'Q' or grid[i] != 'Q'):
               grid[i][j] = ('Q')
   pprint.pprint(grid) #/ how to print one queen per line
```

this is my output. As you can see there are too many `Q`s on the grid:

```
[['-','-','-','-','-','-','Q','-'],
 ['-','-','-','-','Q','Q','-','-']
 ['-','-','-','-','Q','-','-','-']
 ['Q','Q','-','-','-','Q','Q','-']
 ['-','-','Q','-','Q','-','-','-'].
```

Comment: Step one would be fixing your indentation.

Comment: Step two should be to fix the syntax error in your if-statement

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Must they also not be on the same diagonal.

Comment: Start with a 2 x 2, and get it working, then a 4 x 4, then an 8 x 8.

Comment: @lanAdul the code is working, my out put has a two queen per line or no queen per line

Comment: @PeterWood ik, i have a different code witch i import itertools and it does give me the result i want

Comment: Step 3: Fix `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` (your grid is 1x8, not 8x8)

Comment: And then step 4, show us your output

Comment: @Eric i add some of output

Comment: What's this `import random/ i import this classes`

Comment: Code still doesn't actually run without an exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

1. You've got one too many loops. You can loop over the first index `i`, then just insert the `Q` where `randrange` tells you.
2. Your [`randrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange) call is wrong. It should have a start and a stop. In fact, `rangerange` is not the right tool here if you want your `Q`s to be unique in row *and* column.
3. Your grid set up doesn't actually produce what you show it producing.

Here's all three things fixed:

```
In [34]: size = 8
In [35]: grid = [['-' for m in range(size)] for n in range(size)]
In [36]: insertPoints = range(size) # = list(range(size)) in Python 3
In [37]: random.shuffle(insertPoints)
In [38]: for i in range(size):
   ....:     grid[i][insertPoints[i]] = "Q"
```

Which gives:

```
In [39]: grid
Out[39]: 
[['-', '-', '-', 'Q', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['-', 'Q', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'Q', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'Q', '-', '-'],
 ['Q', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', 'Q', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'Q'],
 ['-', '-', 'Q', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']]
```

*(See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20484205/2071807) for why shuffling a range doesn't work in Python 3)*

Comment: we still have Q on top of each other

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes, I didn't quite read closely enough. I'll fix it.

Comment: import random
size = 8
grid = [['-' for m in range(size)] for n in range(size)]
insertPoints = range(size)
random.shuffle(insertPoints)
for i in range(size):
   grid[i][insertPoints[i]] = "Q"                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Odisho\Downloads\8queens.py", line 5, in <module>
    random.shuffle(insertPoints)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\random.py", line 272, in shuffle
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment
>>>

Comment: @LondanRob i got the error message    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Odisho\Downloads\8queens.py", line 5, in <module>
    random.shuffle(insertPoints)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\random.py", line 272, in shuffle
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment
>>>

Comment: Ah, I think we have a Python 2.7 vs Python 3 problem here. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20484205/2071807) for your solution.

Comment: @LondonRay i believe problem is  """ random.shuffle(insertPoints)""'

Comment: Yes. I've already fixed the question. Use the code in the comment to line `In[36]` and the `shuffle` should work. [Here](https://repl.it/tZf) is the Python 3 code you need.

Comment: @LondanRay, sorry to bother you this much, but it prints none when i run it.